# How do I save instance of List<Fragments>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a ArrayList of Fragments :  `ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList;`

**I want to save the instance of Fragments List when I change orientation on Android Studio. How do I do so?**

I tried to do this on OnSaveInstanceState method:

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList(C_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) arrayList);
```

but on my onCreate method:

```
arrayList = (ArrayList<Fragment>) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(C_KEY);
```

does not work because of the error:Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.util.ArrayList<android.os.Parcelable>' to 'java.util.ArrayList<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your onCreate method your casting is incorrect.

instead of

```
arrayList = (ArrayList<Fragment>) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(C_KEY);
```

put

```
arrayList = (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(C_KEY);
```

Another option is using `ViewModel`

Comment: I tried that too but it does not work because my arrayList is a type of Fragment.

Comment: My arrayList is an arraylist of fragment. Each fragment contains a webview. All of these webview are fragments in ViewPager and sets an adapter of FragmentStatePagerAdapter